# How to enable verbosegc on Bluemix WebSphere liberty profile

Tags: garbage-collection, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I'm quite new to Bluemix and have been playing around a bit with the WebSphere liberty profile using a sample application.  I used the Monitoring and Analytics service in order to get some performance related data, but this doesn't provide enough data to truly analyse the application's behaviour.

In order to truly analyze the behaviour of the JVM, I would need verbose Garbage Collection logging.  I tried to activate this through the environment variables, by adding for Name "verbose" and Value "gc", combined with "Xloggc" and "verbosegc.log".  The application started fine, but no logs were created.

**Question:**
Does anyone know how to activate verbosegc logging for liberty on Bluemix?

Basically I could extend the question to all GC related parameters... GC Policy, Nursery size.  Is it possible to control such variables in Bluemix?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by going into your Liberty configuration and adding the `verbose:gc` option to your `jvm.options` file.

Here is the location of `jvm.options` file in bluemix:

[image: Location of jvm.options for Liberty in bluemix]

There will be a bunch of JVM options in there by default.
Insert this option into the file on it's own line:
`-verbose:gc`

for additional garbage collection infomartion, these options may also be useful:
`-XX:+PrintGCDetails` *(OpenJDK only)*
`-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps` *(OpenJDK only)*

For more info on customizing the JVM for Liberty, see the following:

- [Customizing the Liberty environment](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html)
- [Bluemix - Customizing the JRE](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html#customizingjre)

Comment: Note, the default for Bluemix is to use the IBM JRE, but `-XX:PrintGCDetails` and `-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps` are OpenJDK options.  OP said `-Xloggc`, so perhaps they're using OpenJDK, or perhaps they didn't know they needed to use `-Xverbosegclog` on IBM JREs.

Comment: Thanks Brett, I clarified that those two options were for OpenJDK only.  The key point is adding `-verbose:gc` which will work on either JDK.

Comment: Thanks!  Just one more thing...  I didn't find a way to directly edit files in Bluemix.  Is there any?  Or is it only possible via the "cf" command line argurments or via Eclipse?

Comment: Yep, you would edit this file the same way you edit and push any other file to Bluemix (using cf or Eclipse tools).